# Filling up "None" values in pandas dataframe with values from previous column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am calling an API which returns a JSON-file. When I parse the JSON file to a pandas dataframe it returns the following table:

| Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total | Category1 | Category 1.2 |
| Total | None | None |
| Total | Category 2 | None |
| Total | Category 2 | Category 2.1 |
| Total | Category 3 | None |
| Total | Category 3 | Category 3.1 |

As you can see there are three levels of categories. I would like to replace the "None" values in the columns with the value from the column before. The dataframe should be looking like this:

| Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total | Category1 | Category 1.2 |
| Total | **Total** | **Total** |
| Total | Category 2 | **Category 2** |
| Total | Category 2 | Category 2.1 |
| Total | Category 3 | **Category 3** |
| Total | Category 3 | Category 3.1 |

I already experimented with some loops and with the following code:

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
   df.iloc[:,i] = np.where(df.iloc[:,i] == "None",df.iloc[:,i+1],df.iloc[:,i])
```

But this does not work. How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your `None` are actually `np.nan`, and then your task will be made simple as forward fill along the columns `ffill(axis=1)` will do what you need:

```
df.replace('None',np.nan,inplace=True)
df_f = df.ffill(axis=1)

print(df_f)

  Level 1     Level 2       Level 3
0   Total   Category1  Category 1.2
1   Total       Total         Total
2   Total  Category 2    Category 2
3   Total  Category 2  Category 2.1
4   Total  Category 3    Category 3
5   Total  Category 3  Category 3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) works on the Python `None` object. Pass `axis=1` to fill across columns:

```
filled = df.ffill(axis=1)

print(filled)
  Level 1     Level 2       Level 3
0   Total   Category1  Category 1.2
1   Total       Total         Total
2   Total  Category 2    Category 2
3   Total  Category 2  Category 2.1
4   Total  Category 3    Category 3
5   Total  Category 3  Category 3.1
```